# Не работает контроллер java

Tags: java, json, post, rest

Нужно написать контроллер, который принимает json формата

```
[{"dateOfBirth":"2011-05-11"},{"dateOfBirth":"2021-02-01"}]
```

высчитывает количество человек и их возраст и возвращает определенную сумму
Перепробовал все. Ошибка 400 или 500. Помогите плиз.
Вот контроллер:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/insurance/*")
public class InsuranceController {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InsuranceController.class);

    @Autowired
    private InsuranceService insuranceService;
    @Autowired
    private InsuredDTO insuredDTO;

    @PostMapping(value = "/tickCalculate", consumes = "application/json")
    @CheckSession
    @CatchExceptionReport
    public ResponseEntity<?> tickCalculate(@RequestBody ArrayList<InsuredDTO> insuredDTO)
    {
        try {
            int resultCalculate = insuranceService.getCalculation(insuredDTO);
            return new ResponseEntity<Object>(resultCalculate, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Something wrong: ", e);
            return new ResponseEntity<Object>(new StatusResponse(Constants.ERROR, e.getMessage()), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
}
```

ДТО:

```
@Data
@Component
public class InsuredDTO {

    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    public LocalDate dateOfBirth;

    public int getAge() {return Period.between(this.dateOfBirth, LocalDate.now()).getYears();}
}
```

Сервис:

```
@Service
public class InsuranceService {

    @Autowired
    InsuredDTO insuredDTO;

    public int getCalculation(ArrayList<InsuredDTO> ages) {
        return ages.stream()
                .mapToInt(InsuredDTO::getAge)
                .map(age -> age < 18 ? 360 : 320)
                .sum();
    }
}
```

логи:

```
thread=sse-nio-8443-exec-94 class_path=.controllers.ControllerValidationHandler phone= sessionID= message="org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Text '2011-05-11' could not be parsed at index 2; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Text '2011-05-11' could not be parsed at index 2 (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->ru.nskes.pserver.dtos.insurance.InsuredDTO[\"dateOfBirth\"])
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Text '2011-05-11' could not be parsed at index 2; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Text '2011-05-11' could not be parsed at index 2 (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->ru.nskes.pserver.dtos.insurance.InsuredDTO[\"dateOfBirth\"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Верный формат запроса [{"dateOfBirth":"11.05.2021"},{"dateOfBirth":"01.02.2021"}]